# Android - how to change the name of the app when it appears on peoples downloaded app lists

Tags: android

How do I change the name of the app as it appears on the phone after the person has downloaded it and sees it browsing through their downloaded apps?

And how do I tell how the name is appearing for them now?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/change-app-name-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android manifest you have:
`<application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >`
Under res/values/strings.xml of your project you can change:
`<string name="app_name">My title</string>`

Answer (score 2):

You cant change it dynamically. Once its compiled, then it will remain the same. However, you can provide different names for different locales.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339529/can-you-change-your-app-name-this-under-icon-in-list-of-application-dynamicall)